# JQuery dynamic html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the button is pressed i would like for another div tag to appear on the screen for the user. I have tried and looked through many web pages to see what is going wrong. There is no error on the console for the webpage. Here is the HTML code and JavaScript code.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$("buttonId").click(function () {
    var structure = $("<div>Hello world</div>");
    $("#newDiv").append(structure);
    document.getElementById("div01").style.backgroundColor = "red";
});



<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <p class="logo"> Logo! </p>
            <ul id="ul01">
                <li><a href="#" class="active">NewsFeed</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Following</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="logIn">
                <a href="#"> Login </a>
                <a href="#"> Sign Up </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <a id="buttonId" href="#"> Click fo anouther div!!</a>
        <div id=newDiv>
            <div id=div01> Hello </div>
        </div>
        <script src="operations.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$("#buttonId")`?!...

Comment: `$("buttonId")`will not match your element. It  should be `$("#buttonId")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("buttonId")` is a selector that won't match any element (as it searches for an element with a tag `buttonId`).

You should change it to `$("#buttonId")` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There were some mistakes in your code.

```
$("buttonId").click(function () {
    var structure = $("<div>Hello world</div>");
    $("#newDiv").append(structure);
    document.getElementById("div01").style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

In the above code. # character is missing before buttonId. So it will not match anything. This is the corrected version

```
$("#buttonId").click(function () {
        var structure = $("<div>Hello world</div>");
        $("#newDiv").append(structure);
        document.getElementById("div01").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
```

Also in your HTML, you have forgotten to place double quotes outside ids of newDiv and div01. Here is the corrected version

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <p class="logo"> Logo! </p>
            <ul id="ul01">
                <li><a href="#" class="active">NewsFeed</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discover</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Following</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="logIn">
                <a href="#"> Login </a>
                <a href="#"> Sign Up </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <a id="buttonId" href="#"> Click fo anouther div!!</a>
        <div id="newDiv">
            <div id="div01"> Hello </div>
        </div>
        <script src="operations.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're missing the '#' sign in front of your $('buttonId').

So it should be:

```
    $("#buttonId").click(function () {
        var structure = $("<div>Hello world</div>");
        $("#newDiv").append(structure);
        document.getElementById("div01").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
```

Cheers,

David